Getting the contents of a message in Discord.py
I have been trying to get the contents of a message in Discord.py so I can display it at the bottom of the message my bot sends back. Every example I have seen online has been to check for certain phrases to trigger a command but not to print the message back.
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="=", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("The bot is now running.")

@bot.command()
async def copycat(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Copy Cat", description=message.content, color=0x3cc13c)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

bot.run(TOKEN)


To get the message content, you can use ctx.message.content and then put it wherever you need it to be. Replace description=message.content in your embed code with description=ctx.message.content.
Another solution is to use Interactions with slash commands using @tree.command (this involves using Client instead of Bot):
import discord
from discord import app_commands

# Define client and tree
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

# Define your command
@tree.command(
    name="commandname", # Enter your command name here, it will turn out to be /<name>
    description="My first application Command", # What shows up in the dialog
)
async def first_command(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello!") # You can use f-strings here
    # And to get the message content...
    await interaction.followup.send_message(f"{interaction.message.content}") # Use followup to send other messages on top

# And then sync it in on_ready:
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync()
    # other code here

To make more commands, just use @tree.command with those parameters and then use async def with the same structure.
Hope this helps!

Thank you very much! This is the fix to my problem!
